# How to recreate Tailwind background transition-color?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I saw the special color on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transition-property in **dark mode**
Here's the pic [image]

I want to know how can I recreate this ? With gradient color or other css property?

I tried to see how they did it by inspecting their css only found

```css
--tw-bg-opacity: 1;
background-color: rgb(15 23 42/var(--tw-bg-opacity));
```

Which is only a background color.

If you know how to do this, please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They implemented it by adding an image inside the body
here is how they implemented it from the inspector

[image: how tailwind implemented it]

and here is the link for the image they have used:
https://tailwindcss.com/_next/static/media/docs-dark@30.77f062b5fd90f0d2cd4752cd9a8649c8.avif